# Finding a side of a triangle with one side, angle and a quotient of two other sides.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Solving a firing-with-prediction puzzle in the game I am developing I found myself looking on the internet of solutions about triangle and its side. It turns out there is very few information about quotient of two sides.

[image]

Let ABC be a triangle. AB = **a**, CB/AC = **b**, ∠CAB = **alpha**. I need to find AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$CB = AC \cdot$ **b** $= xb$. Now use the law of cosines.

Comment: **x** is unknown.

Comment: That led me to a quadratic equation. Thx.